# What functions are included in apply_filter('the_content')

Tags: filters, the-content

There is a function called apply_filter where you can use it like this:

```
echo apply_filter('the_content', $my_content);
```

It add formatting tags and clean up the content.

**Trac or docs**

I looked in the trac and docs but could not find what functions are used in the apply_filter function.

**I found wpautop**

The only one I found was wpautop:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

What more? Hint me to the trac or some docs with a list of functions that are used.

Comment: You could make a function to print the filters for a given hook, see my answer [from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225021/547252) for a function to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the global `$wp_filter` array to check for callbacks on each filter. Here is for example a code snippet that prints out all the callbacks on the `the_content` filter in the footer part of your theme:

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
        global $wp_filter;
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $wp_filter['the_content'],true));
});
```

The priority `10` part could look like this:

```
   [10] => Array
        (
            [wptexturize] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wptexturize
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [convert_smilies] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_smilies
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [convert_chars] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_chars
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [wpautop] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wpautop
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [shortcode_unautop] => Array
                (
                    [function] => shortcode_unautop
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [prepend_attachment] => Array
                (
                    [function] => prepend_attachment
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

        )
```